# App de kiosko a pantalla completa

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

He hecho una aplicación de kiosko para Chrome, pero pese a ser esta de kiosko no consigo ponerla del todo a pantalla completa puesto que se sigue viendo la barra superior y la de herramientas del SO. 
En background_main.js he añadido la línea state:'fullscreen', así como el permiso en el manifest.json para 'fullscreen', pero sigue sin funcionar. este es mi código de background_main.js:

```
 var runApp = function() {
      if (chrome.power) {
        chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');
      }
      console.log(config);
      chrome.app.window.create(
          config ?
          'exported_app_view.html' :
          'designer_view.html',
          {
            id: 'KioskDesignerWindow',
            width: 1100,
            height: 720,
            minWidth: 800,
            minHeight: 600,
            state: 'fullscreen' 
          },
          function(win) {
            if (!this.X) { return; }
            var window = win.contentWindow;
            window.onload = function() {
              this.$addWindow(window);
              var Y = this.X.subWindow(window, 'Kiosk Designer Window');
              this.DOM.init(Y);
            }.bind(this);
            win.onClosed.addListener(function() {
              this.$removeWindow(window);
            }.bind(this));
          }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
```

Comment: Prueba con `chrome.app.window.current().fullscreen();`

Comment: Ferdoqui: es un código que use hace tiempo, tamdo de los ejemplos de Google, y como puedes ver le digo "prueba con", porque no se si será la solución  y a su problema. Según lo que comenta y viendo el código todo parece estar  bien. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/window-state/window.js

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que se inicia el modo kiosko puede variar según el SO.

¿Has creado el acceso directo y configurado sus propiedades?

Para Windows 10 se debe hacer lo siguiente:

Una vez creado el acceso directo, se le tiene que dar a propiedades, en la ruta de destino, después del .exe, se tiene que añadir lo siguiente:

--kiosk url --kiosk

Después aplicar y aceptar. Luego reinicias el pc y ya debería salir en modo pantalla completa.